# Javascript - Make object from another object through iteration/recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion

The object I have is e.g.

```
[
    [
        ["first_name", "==", "tom"], "||", ["first_name", "==", "harry"]
    ], "&&", ["gender", "==", "m"]
]
```

The object I am trying to build from above is:

```
{
  "condition": "&&",
  "rules": [
    {
      "field": "gender",
      "operator": "==",
      "value": "m"
    },
    {
      "condition": "||",
      "rules": [
        {
         "field": "first_name",
          "operator": "==",
          "value": "tom"
        },
        {
          "field": "first_name",
          "operator": "==",
          "value": "harry"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**What have I tried?**

Well this feels so complicated right now that I cannot even come up with an initial concept. It seems to me that a recursive function call would be a good start.

**What am I trying to achieve?**

I have these rules inside an object and I want to convert them into [Query Builder](http://querybuilder.js.org/demo.html) rules.

Can this be done with iteration/recursion and without actually using a lexer and parser? If so, then how would you do it? Browser JS solutions only please.

**Please Note**

The object can be n-level deep, so the solution has to be able to take that into account.

Comment: I don't really mind the neg-votes, but please care to explain why you did? That would be helpful for me in future ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a simple recursive function which returns by having two arrays a condition type object and otherwise one object with operator.

```js
function getObject(array) {
    return Array.isArray(array[0]) && Array.isArray(array[2])
        ? { condition: array[1], rules: [getObject(array[0]), getObject(array[2])] }
        : { field: array[0], operator: array[1], value: array[2] };
}

var data = [[["first_name", "==", "tom"], "||", ["first_name", "==", "harry"]], "&&", ["gender", "==", "m"]],
    result = getObject(data);
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Well this seems to be the most elegant solution, so I am accepting it as answer. I thank everyone for their solutions nevertheless. SOF rocks!

Answer (score 1):

```
var example = [
  [
    ["first_name", "==", "tom"], "||", ["first_name", "==", "harry"]
  ], 
  "&&", 
  ["gender", "==", "m"]
]

function recursion(array) {
  var result = {};
  if (array[1] !== '==') {
    result.condition = array[1];
    result.rules = [recursion(array[0]), recursion(array[2])];
  } else {
    result.field = array[0];
    result.operator = array[1];
    result.value = array[2];
  }

  return result;
}

console.log(recursion(example));
```

Maybe this can get you startet? You of cause have to add some checks, because this function expects the array to look exactly like your example and will fail if the input is unexpected.

Comment: Thanks a ton. Let me give it a try. I will accept the answer in a bit, if it works :)

Comment: Your answer will not work for conditions other than ==

Comment: That's why I only wanted to get him started. I wrote just that in the answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Have tested this solution and it works as you expect but you have to handle failure scenarios. Hope it helps you.

```
var arr = [
    [
        ["first_name", "==", "tom"],
        "||",
        ["first_name", "==", "harry"]
    ],
    "&&",
    ["gender", "==", "m"]
];

function processArray(arr) {
    if (Array.isArray(arr[0])) {
        return {
            condition: arr[1],
            rules: [processArray(arr[0]), processArray(arr[2])]
        };
    } else {
        return {
            field: arr[0],
            operator: arr[1],
            value: arr[2]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution. let me give it a try too. :)